# How can I display extensions in windows explorer in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

How can I display extensions in windows explorer in windows 7? There used to be an option in XP, but I can't find it in Win 7.

Comment: file extensions?

Comment: Like .exe, .pdf etc. The long descriptions of a file type are totally not readable for me, I just want to see .h rather than "Microsoft Visual C++..." (the rest being truncated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Press Alt (or Organize>Layout>Menu bar and check it)

2) Select Tools -> Folder options -> view -> Files and Folders (un-click hide extensions for known file types).

Comment: Ah cool, much better now! I didn't know about (1), cheers!

Comment: `You can accept an answer in 7 minutes` - this web site is getting more annoying to use every day :(

Comment: @Grzenio +1 ... I hear ya bro.

Comment: @Grzenio At least you accept answers. I have only been here 20 days, and there are already people, whose questions I won't bother with. So thank you for your diligence.

Comment: @Grzenio By the way, instead of holding down ALT, you can also click Organize>Layout>Menu bar and check it. you will then be able to find it like old XP.

Comment: @KCotreau.... +1 for thoroughness :-)

Answer (score 6):

Try (in an Explorer Window) Tools > Folder Options > View Tab > Untick "Hide extensions for known files types".

[image]